# DatetimePicker asp.net Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i need help 
why this is doesn't work when i putting == instead of <= or >=
with <= or >= working 
**My view is**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CTR", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="input-group col-md-5 col-md-push-3">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Date:</span>
          @Html.TextBox("date", null, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Choose Date" })
          <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class=" btn btn-success" type="submit" value="search">Go</button>
          </span>
    </div>
}
```

**And Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date)
 {
      Debug.WriteLine(date);

      return View(db.Ctrs.Include(d => d.Citizens).Include(d => d.Exchange).Include(d => d.Tariffs).Where(d => d.Exchange.Date == date).ToList());         
 }
```

Comment: What is not working? Do the values in you database have a time component (in which case only a `DateTime` with the exact date and time will match

Comment: Yep , have 
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
when i compare with == doesn't work :( dsnt show information by date

Answer (score 1):

We need to know what's your database holding, what's your input and your output.
Btw if you want to compare by day, you need to get only the date component of your dates. [MSDN: `System.DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

At the end I think you need to do

```
d => d.Exchange.Date.Value.Date == date.Value.Date
```

In addition, you surely need to manage null values.